# Look up value for another row

Tags: excel, lookup, rank

I have a set of 50 scores, and then of their ranking within the set. I want create a list of certain ranks and return their score.

So I need to lookup from the ranks and return the score that corresponds.

One issue I notice I have from a lot of the Excel tutorials online is that I'm not referencing a row/column next to the lookup value. Notice in the screen grab I have value sets A and B and then later across the sheet I have ranks for their values and then I have a column where I have listed ranks in order and I want to report the value for that set at that rank. So the value in the "S" column needs to look up the number value `1` in "I" and then report the value at that row in the "C" column.

Imgur screen shot[image: http://imgur.com/TMLI1Zk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could leverage an INDEX MATCH here (based on your description, I can't see the screenshot).

If I understand correctly, though, you have the rank listed in Col I, and the score in Col C.

```
=INDEX(C$1:C$20,MATCH(1,I$1:I$20,0))
```

That will figure out how far down the list rank 1 is, and then go that far down Col C and return the value.